# Не удаляются СМС через ContentProvider

Tags: java, android, sms

Пытаюсь удалить СМСку по значению ее поля "_id". Метод отрабатывает без ошибок(не считая того, что rowcount=0), но СМС не удаляется(при последующем запуске приложения она опять на месте и стандартный СМС  менеджер ее тоже видит). В манифесте выставлены права:

```
*uses-permission android:name= "android.permission.WRITE_SMS"*
```

ошибок в логах про недостаточность прав тоже нет.

Версия Андроид KITKAT 4.4.2

Что самое интересное на втором смартфоне, тоже Lenovo P780, но с Android 4.2.2 СМСка удаляется.

Заранее извиняюсь за неопрятный код, если мешает пониманию готов переделать и оставить только относящееся к вопросу.

```
public class SMSListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String LOGTAG = "Bogdan";
ArrayList<SMSItem> SMSList = null;
List<SMSItem> ItemsForAdapter = new ArrayList<SMSItem>();
final static int TOPX = 1000;// максимум SMS которых нужно прочитать, После отладки убрать параметр.
SMSInbox smsboxminer;// объект посредством которого осуществляется доступ к СМС

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Context cont1;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms_list);
    //Log.d(LOGTAG, "call onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) from class: " + this.getLocalClassName());
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(getTitle());
    Apptitle = toolbar.getTitle().toString();
    buttdelsms = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ButtonDel);

    View.OnClickListener buttdelsmsonclicklistener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String txtTotost="";
            String SMSIDs ="";
            long SumtraceTime=0;
            int rowcount = 0;

            Iterator It = currentsellist.iterator();
            while (It.hasNext()) {
                int arrayID = (Integer) It.next();
                //запоминаем ID СМС которые будут удаляться, чтобы потом вывести результат.
                SMSIDs= SMSIDs+";"+SMSList.get(arrayID).getSMSID();
                txtTotost = txtTotost+SMSList.get(arrayID).getSMSID()+"|"+SMSList.get(arrayID).getphone()+"|"+SMSList.get(arrayID).getbody() +"\n";
                /// Написать здесь код удаления СМС
                long start = System.nanoTime();
                /*
                Uri mUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"+"/"+SMSList.get(arrayID).getSMSID());
                Log.d(SMSListActivity.LOGTAG,"delete SMS whith URI="+mUri.getEncodedQuery()+"_id="+SMSList.get(arrayID).getSMSID());
                smsboxminer.mycontext.getContentResolver().delete(mUri, null, null);
                */

                rowcount=smsboxminer.removeSMS(SMSList.get(arrayID).getSMSID());// очень медленно работает. 1 смс - минута.
                //callresult=smsboxminer.removeSMS(5444);// очень медленно работает. 1 смс - минута.
                long end = System.nanoTime();
                long traceTime = end - start; //считаем сколько выполнялся метод
                SumtraceTime = SumtraceTime+traceTime;
                // Отладочная информация
                //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"I will be delete:"+ txtTotost+" checked SMS!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d(SMSListActivity.LOGTAG, "SMSID:"+SMSList.get(arrayID).getSMSID() +" Time to execute removeSMS:"+
                        (double) traceTime / 1000000000 + "s. Rowcount = "+rowcount);
            }
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"SMS delete checked SMS:"+SMSIDs+" in  "+(double) SumtraceTime / 1000000000 + "seconds.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            buttdelsms.setEnabled(false);
            buttdelsms.setText("");
            // TODO не снимается галочка с чекбокса и не удаляется СМСка
        }
    };
    buttdelsms.setOnClickListener(buttdelsmsonclicklistener);

    minputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    buttonsearch = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ButtonSearch);
    currentsellist = new HashSet<Integer>();
    // Скрываем кнопку удаления  до тех пор пока не отмечены элементы.
    buttdelsms.setEnabled(false);
    // fab идентификатор кнопки Email
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action Действие", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();


        }
    });


    // Блок чтения и вывода SMS
    //final SMSInbox smsboxminer;// this передаем Actitvity с которым создаваемому классу нужно будет работать.
    cont1 = this.getApplicationContext();
    smsboxminer = new SMSInbox(cont1, "content://sms");
    // Cоздаем листенер для обработки нажатия чекбокса
    // не забыть привязать этот листенер к самому чекбоксу методом
    // {имя чекбокса}.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList);
    // по идее тут текста быть не дложно, но на всякий случай, чтоб не было ошибок

    // первичное наполнение списка смс. на старте
    if (minputSearch.getText().length() == 0) {
        SMSList = smsboxminer.getSMS(TOPX);
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name + "(" + SMSList.size() + ")");
    }

    View recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.sms_list);
    assert recyclerView != null;
    setupRecyclerView((RecyclerView) recyclerView);


    //Связываем данные массива с элементом ListView:

    if (findViewById(R.id.sms_detail_container) != null) {
        // The detail container view will be present only in the
        // large-screen layouts (res/values-w900dp).
        // If this view is present, then the
        // activity should be in two-pane mode.
        mTwoPane = true;
    }

}
```

Код метода removeSMS класса SMSInbox:

```
public int removeSMS(int SMSID) {
    int rowcounts = 0;
    Uri  mUri = Uri.parse(myUristr+"/"+SMSID);
   Log.d(SMSListActivity.LOGTAG,"delete SMS whith URI="+myUristr+"/"+SMSID);

    rowcounts = mycontext.getContentResolver().delete(mUri, null, null);
    //rowcounts = mycontext.getContentResolver().delete(mUri, null, null);
    return rowcounts;
}
```

логи:

```
07-29 16:34:00.621 23251-23251/com.example.b_.myapplication D/Bogdan:  currentsellist size =   1
07-29 16:34:01.510 23251-23251/com.example.b_.myapplication D/Bogdan: delete SMS whith URI=content://sms/2789
07-29 16:34:02.041 23251-23251/com.example.b_.myapplication D/Bogdan: SMSID:2789 Time to execute removeSMS:0.528256s. Rowcount = 0*
```

Comment: А на чём СМСка хранится? Может ещё доступ к хранилищу данных нужно получить?

Comment: СМС хранится в SQLLite. Доступ пытаюсь через стандартный механизм андроида ContentProvider.Имеется ввиду что доступ еще к БД получить?

Comment: Ну да. На каком хранилище живёт файл базы? Может он расположен нестандартно на телефоне. И получается, что мы лезем к базе, а она живёт (допустим) на съёмной флешке. Здравый смысл подсказывает, что врядли всё так. Но вероятность есть.

Comment: Очень навряд ли так как используя этот же механизм (использование contentprovider)я успешно получаю содержимое СМС в том числе и ее поле  "_id", по которому пытаюсь ее потом удалить.

Comment: Тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614211/deleting-android-sms-programatically пишут, что нужно дать андройду время на то, чтобы он смог получить доступ к СМС и произвести действие. Рекомендуют сделать хендлер для запроса на удаление и подождать 1-2 секунды.

Comment: "Please consider that you can't delete SMS messages on devices with Android 4.4." - оттуда же. Т.е. нужно смириться с тем, что на Андройде 4.4. смс мы удалить не можем.

Comment: Точнее так: не может просто приложение удалить СМС. А предустановленное (умолчальное, default) - может. И в ответах есть ссылка на то, как сделать приложение умолчальным (предустановленным): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247949/how-can-i-create-a-project-in-android-studio-to-function-default-sms-app

Comment: Спасибо. Я этот топик уже перечитывал, но обращал внимание только на ответы с большим количеством голосов. До конца не читал. Как то не верится в такую параною. Но судя по моему опыту видимо это дестйвительно так. Попробую ломом. Напрямую из БД  удалять. Без всяких религиозных обрядов.

Comment: Успехов!) Расскажите потом, пожалуйста, о результатах.

Comment: Нашел подтверждение в офиц документации: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html
"Also, the system now allows **only the default app to write message data to the provider**, although other apps can read at any time."